# All requests seem to be coming from 127.0.0.1 using Tomcat on Azure

Tags: java, tomcat, azure

I am using Azure's Web App service and running a Tomcat instance.  I want to restrict access to the manager app by IP, which is simple enough to set up however there is one issue, according to Tomcat all requests(remote and local) seem to be coming from 127.0.0.1.  Is there any way in Azure to make sure that the X-Forwarded-For header gets set correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Due to Azure load balance, it seems that the Azure website instance could get the request from 127.0.0.1. So we can use "X-Forwarded-For" to get IP.
If the request contains X-Forwarded-For header, the first IP in it should be the one we are looking for, "x-forwarded-for" is reputed to be a defacto standard, however, if the client exists on a private network and connects to the internet via a NAT gateway, you will get the IP of NAT server, not the client, refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For for more information about X-Forwarded-For. Please try to use the following code to get the client IP.

```
      String ip = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");  
      if (ip == null) {  
         ip = request.getRemoteAddr();  
      }
```

You can see this [test result.](http://willtest.azurewebsites.net/TestIP/function.jsp)